# Bootstrap responsive, affixed Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3, so i tried to create a navbar when i scroll then fix it to top.
The best solution in my oppinion was the "affix" from bootstrap, i solve this with js

```
$(document).ready(function(){/* affix the navbar after scroll below header */
    $('#nav').affix({
          offset: {
            top: $('header').height()-$('#nav').height()
          }
    }); 
});
```

But i have a big problem, my menu has about 10 parents and each parent li has a child ul so the navbar has a big height and i cant scroll down the navbar, when i do, just the body scrolls... can you help me?

here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x80cqj0c/ (not beautiful but u can see what i mean)

Answer (score 0):

**[Check This DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/uzfn8vy8/9/)**

add this **css**

```
.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:5;
}



@media screen and (max-width : 760px){ 
#men{
    float:left;
width:100%;
overflow-y: auto;
height: 100px;
}
}
```

**HTML Part**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse affix" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NEWS</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Parent 1</a></li>
           <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               Parent 2 <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="'">Child</a></li>
                             <li><a href="'">Child</a></li>
                             <li><a href="'">Child</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="'">Child</a></li>
                             <li><a href="'">Child</a></li>
                             <li><a href="'">Child</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="'">Child</a></li>
                             <li><a href="'">Child</a></li>
                             <li><a href="'">Child</a></li>

           </ul>
         </li>

       <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               Parent 2 <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="'">Child</a></li>
                             <li><a href="'">Child</a></li>
                             <li><a href="'">Child</a></li>
                <li><a href="'">Child</a></li></ul></li>

         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               VIDEOS <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">TRAILERS </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">POPULAR VIDEOS </a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Audio launch in US is a bad idea </a></li>
               <li><a href="#">SHORTS </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OTHERS </a></li>

           </ul>
         </li>
           <li><a href="#about">INTERVIEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">KIDS</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

</nav>

<div class="section_divider_grau"></div>
     <section id="welcome_container" style="
    padding-top: 60px;
">
            <div class="container" id="section1">
               <div class="col-md-12 normal">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
               </div>
            </div>
         </section>
```

Comment: same issue... if the screen is small enought just the body scrolls and navigation stays static...

Comment: i just want to go throught the whole menu so that when i am @mobile device that i can scroll througt the menu yeah